# How to update a variable inside another variable and have both reflect the change using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables

I am extremely new to JavaScript and have run into a problem with my code:

```
var ImgNumber =1;

var ImgSelect = '#gallery img:nth-of-type(' +ImgNumber+ ')';

    while (ImgNumber!=4) {
        ImgNumber++;    
        console.log(ImgSelect);
    };
```

What I would like to happen is for the readout to say

```
#gallery img:nth-of-type(1)
#gallery img:nth-of-type(2)
#gallery img:nth-of-type(3)
```

But what happens is

```
#gallery img:nth-of-type(1)
#gallery img:nth-of-type(1)
#gallery img:nth-of-type(1)
```

So is there a way to update ImgSelect to reflect the change in ImgNumber?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
var ImgSelect = '#gallery img:nth-of-type(' +ImgNumber+ ')';
```

what is doing is assigning the value of `"#gallery img:nth-of-type(1)"` to the variable `ImgSelect`, so the number won't change inside the string so easily.

But what you can do is a new function to achieve this:

```
var ImgSelect = function(ImgNumber){
     return '#gallery img:nth-of-type(' +ImgNumber+ ')';
}
```

To Use the function:

```
while (ImgNumber!=4) {
    ImgNumber++;    
    console.log(ImgSelect(ImgNumber));
};
```

Or you can use a function like this, due to that the variable `ImgNumber` is a global one:

```
var ImgSelect = function(){
     return '#gallery img:nth-of-type(' +ImgNumber+ ')';
}
```

To Use the function:

```
while (ImgNumber!=4) {
    ImgNumber++;    
    console.log(ImgSelect());
};
```

Comment: You shouldn't advice using global variables. Moreover, the OP's code can actually reside within a function. BTW, your syntax is incorrect: use `function` instead of `var` in your examples.

Comment: Sorry, I did't notice my mistake. I forgot to use the word function. Thanx. And the global variable I used is because in the question is used like that.

Comment: No, as I already said, the code in the question might actually live inside a function that's not shown, because it's not relevant for the question.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I have one quick question. Is there any difference between writing the function like you did `var ImgSelect = function(ImgNumber) {}` and like this `function ImgSelect (ImgNumber) {}` ?

Comment: Here you can read about the differences: http://javascript.about.com/library/blfunc.htm
Anyway, there is no practical difference in your example.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to create a function:

```
function ImgSelect(ImgNumber) {
    return '#gallery img:nth-of-type(' + ImgNumber + ')';
}
```

Then call the function in the loop:

```
while (ImgNumber != 4) {
    console.log(ImgSelect(ImgNumber++));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the assignment of `ImgSelect` *within* your `while` loop, otherwise it won't be updated:

```
var ImgSelect, ImgNumber =1;

while (ImgNumber!=4) {
    ImgNumber++;    
    ImgSelect = '#gallery img:nth-of-type(' +ImgNumber+ ')';
    console.log(ImgSelect);
};
```

Comment: I could do that, but I was going to be using it in several places throughout my script and was hoping to not have to write it out each time.

Comment: @cyreb7 – In that case, put the assignment inside a function, like @rdineiu suggested. That said, that practice seems to be a little much overhead to me; can't you just copy-paste it?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is not correct, since you have already defined the variable. Once you define it, you have to assign it to something else before it can *become* anything else. Otherwise it will not change. So, you would have to put the assignment inside the loop.

But what you're really trying to do here should be done with a `for` loop. It's made for this kind of incremental processing:

```
for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    console.log('#gallery img:nth-of-type(' + i + ')');
}
```

Basically, this says, "Starting at `1`, keep increasing `i` until it's less than `4`, and each time do what's inside the `{ }`."

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I am still new to JavaScript and I forgot about the 'for' loop.